# Convert plain text formulas into Latex Syntax so that I can use MathJax to show them in a web page

Tags: code, text

We have a set of Formulas like these-

1. Area of rectangle=breadth*(sqrt((diagonal)^2-(breadth)^2))
2. Annuity Payment=(rate_per_period*present_value)/(1-(1+rate_per_period)^-number_of_periods)
3. Volume of Capsule=pi*(radius)^2*((4/3)*radius+side)

We are looking for code/API to convert the above into Latex Syntax so that I can use MathJax to show them in a web page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will fints mathjax's ascimath input jax will take them as written

Comment: I removed the plain-tex tag as this is plain _text_ 9and this more or less off topic) not plain TeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsciiMath module with MathJax is a good starting point. Thank you David Charlisle for the comment above.

Please visit http://asciimath.org/ to know more and how to use MathJax's AsciiMath module.

Comment: Can you accept your own answer? Because your question probably will be helpfull for others and this answer as well.